# Nodejs parsing csv file from stream to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-s3

I'm trying to parse a CSV file downloaded from the s3 bucket and then upload it to s3 based on Stream to avoid loading a file to memory - large files.

```
const objectStream = object?.Body as Readable | undefined;

    if (objectStream === undefined) {
        throw new Error('No data');
    }

    const transformationStream = new PassThrough();
    const parserStream = parse({ headers: (headers) => headers.map((header) => header + 'TEST') })
        .on('error', (error) => this.log.error(error))
        .on('data', (row) => this.log.info(JSON.stringify(row)))
        .on('end', (rowCount: number) => this.log.info(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`));

    objectStream.pipe(parserStream).pipe(transformationStream);

    const upload = new Upload({
        client: s3Client,
        params: {
            Bucket: this.bucketName,
            Key: key,
            Body: transformationStream,
        },
    });

    try {
        await upload.done();
    } catch (error) {
        this.log.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
```

but I'm getting an error like the below:

```
"The \"chunk\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object",
"stack": "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"chunk\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:285:13)
    at uo.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
    at uo.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at uo.emit (/var/task/index.js:37:9384)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at uo.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at uo.Transform.push (internal/streams/transform.js:166:32)
    at uo.pushRow (/var/task/index.js:37:11093)"
```

When I drop out the pipe `pipe(parserStream)` the code works fine and the file has been uploading successfully to S3 otherwise getting an error as above.

Comment: I haven't played enough with streams to have a solid answer here but based on the error message I'd bet the parserStream is not outputting string data.  The object it is outputting is going through the transformationStream and into the S3 upload which doesn't like getting objects.  How to fix that, well, not sure.  That's why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I think the problem might be that parser steam is an object stream and you're trying to pipe it to a non-object steam, which is what s3 upload wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `parse` (a method from csv-parse) is array. While input of writable stream in node.js must be string of buffer.
So, as far as I understand `parse` could not be used for standart piping.

Seems that guys from csv-parse implemented their own transformer that could be used in your case:

`stream-transform` (https://csv.js.org/transform/)

See an example from the [documentation](https://csv.js.org/parse/recipes/stream_pipe/):

```
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';
import { generate } from 'csv-generate';
import { transform } from 'stream-transform';

const generator = generate({
  length: 20
});
const parser = parse({
  delimiter: ':'
});
const transformer = transform((record, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, record.join(' ')+'\n');
  }, 500);
}, {
  parallel: 5
});
generator.pipe(parser).pipe(transformer).pipe(process.stdout);
```